# Passing in many parameters to scipy optimize

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, minimize

I'm trying to run an optimization in scipy for a linear regression. I have different beta's and alpha's which I'm trying to optimize over, and the lengths of these beta's and alpha's differ based on the circumstances. Is it possible to do something like:

```
params = [[betas],[alphas]] #beta, alpha of different lengths
minimize(function,params)
```

This obviously doesn't work as I get `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence`. So to get around it, I have been passing in the params as a vector, and then doing:

```
def function(params):
    betas = params[0:k]
    alphas = params[k:j]
```

for some global `j`, `k` variables. However, this is an annoying way to do things, and it is prone to error, so I was wondering if there was an easier way to do it.

Comment: Just a side-note: you could have solved this problem using currying, i.e., having a function that takes `k` and returns a lambda function of `params` that, in turn, refers to that `k`. But let’s wait for ideas that are closer to the context, perhaps there are some.

Comment: Are you using `scipy.optimize.minimize()`? If so, you are likely missing the `x0` parammeter. The interface is `minimize(fun, x0, args=(), ...)` with `x0` beeing the initial guess (with one value for each independent variable of `fun`) and `args` beeing a tupple/list of additional (invariant) parameters to `fun`.  
So I guess your `params` is either supposed to be `x0` or `args`. `x0` must indeed be a flat list, while `args` is supposed to be a tupple/list of arguments (which in turn may be of any type including lists, solely depending on what `fun` expects.)

Comment: Could you please post a minimal example along with your imports?! I agree with @PeterE, you probably just forgot about `x0`; but we can check if you provide a minimal reproducible example.